# HTML: Want to make a button List and the Text doesn't change color

Tags: html, css

I want to make a button that is already finished, I implemented an "h3" but when I hover the button the text doesn't change the colour, how I can do it in CSS.

That's the code of the button:

```html
<button><img src="Images/pack1.png"></img><h3>MVP</h3><h2>10$</h2></button>
```

Next Problem, I want to make that the buttons are adjacent but it doesn't work! I already put them in a list.

That's the code:

```css
 #shop ul li {
   float: right;
   margin: 10px;
   padding-top: 100px;
   padding-bottom: 25px;
 }

 #shop button {
   font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
   width: 400px;
   height: 430px;
   float: right;
   border-radius: 4px;
   border: 2px solid;
   font-size: 15px;
   background-color: #f0f0f0;
   color:#494949;
   margin-right: 1450px;
 }

 #shop button:hover {
   background-color: #494949;
   color: #f0f0f0;
 }
```

```html
  <section id="shop">
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><button><img src="Images/pack1.png"></img><h3>VIP</h3><h2>5$</h2></button></li>
        <li><button><img src="Images/pack1.png"></img><h3>MVP</h3><h2>10$</h2></button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: you don't really need these headers inside button you can add a class to button and give font-size or color property

Comment: Did you check out some of the answers? Consider giving some feedback, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect syntax, `h2` and `h3` cannot be children of `button`. You can remove the button though and still get the desired result. I reworked your code and used flexbox to align your buttons adjacent to one another.

```css
 
#shop ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}
img {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#shop ul li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px;
   padding-top: 100px;
   font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
   width: 400px;
   height: 430px;
   border-radius: 4px;
   border: 2px solid;
   font-size: 15px;
   background-color: #f0f0f0;
   color:#494949;
 }
 
 #shop li:hover {
   background-color: #494949;
   color: #f0f0f0;
 }
```

```html
<section id="shop">
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Felis_catus-cat_on_snow.jpg"><h3>VIP</h3><h2>5$</h2></li>
        <li><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Felis_catus-cat_on_snow.jpg"><h3>MVP</h3><h2>10$</h2></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you did is correct, for displaying the buttons next to each other you could use `display: inline-block`.

```css
button:hover {
  background-color: #494949;
  color: #f0f0f0;
}

.inline {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button>A</button>
<button>B</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the colour of the `h3` or `h2` and  put the buttons inline with each other

```
 #shop button:hover h3,
 #shop button:hover h2 {
   background-color: #494949;
   color: #f0f0f0;
 }

 #shop ul li {
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all your each button has margin-right: 1450px, maybe it's a mistake?
if you need that the buttons were in line, the parent div must be display: flex,
if you change the margin-rigth and parent div - thats will be ok.